# Specifying custom data in Symfony Routing Annotation

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5, php-7.4

I am using symfony 5, and specifying the routings as annotation. So now I have a requirement to pass some extra data along with the routes. It is not part of routing, but I need to have a value for each routing. So I am specifying the route as below, using the options object `options={"label"="COMMMON_CLIENTMANAGEMENT"}`.

It is not producing an error. So I am not sure if it is working or not. Also I have not been able to retrieve the data from any routing services.

```
 *   
 * @Route("/client/list", name="client_list", options={"label"="COMMMON_CLIENTMANAGEMENT"})
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
```

And I want to create an html based on this data, whick will be like `<li href="{{path(route)}}">{{ label }}</li>`

Comment: I guess it depends on the scope where you need that data available. If you need it inside controllers, maybe you can just use extra parameters. Like here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#extra-parameters

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but if the data you need to pass is not part of the route, why do you need to specify it in the annotation in the first place? Why not just define a variable in the method for the controller action?

Comment: @patrick3853 I am implementing something where I need to create some links in html based on the route. So the data that I an setting in the `options.label` will be the text for the href. Like  `<li href="{{path(route)}}">{{ label }}</li>`

Comment: have you considered just adding a translation? like ... `{{ route|trans }}` and have in your translation file a label for each route? could even use a different domain for that so it doesn't clash with other translation, in case you got any. would then be `{{ route|trans({}, 'route_labels') }}`. also scales, if you happen to translate this at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

So I did a bit more experimenting since I gather the intent is to use the 'label' data when listing routes.  I think it is still easier to use the defaults section but you can access the options information using the route collection:

```
class PlayCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:play';

    private RouterInterface $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $routes = $this->router->getRouteCollection();
        $route = $routes->get('index');
        $label = $route->getOption('label');
```

Not sure if there is a way to directly get the route by from inside of twig but it would be easy enough to write a twig extension for this.

Original Answer:

The [defaults](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#extra-parameters) section is used to provide additional information.

I had a hard time finding the docs on the options section.  This [blog article](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-simpler-routing-options-config) talks about some new options such as utf-8 support.  I think the options section is used by the router.  Not positive.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index", options={"label"="COMMMON_CLIENTMANAGEMENT"})
     */
```

Comment: I *assume* OP wants to cycle through some route collection and access the label there, the example in comment (with <li>) seems to imply that ...